# Cannot install python package in Git Bash

Tags: python, bash, git, pip, artifactory

I'm trying to install a package from my company's internal artifactory storage. I'm getting 2 exceptions in Gitbash that I can't understand. When I run Pip Freeze I don't see the install package, so I don't believe it is already installed.

After reading the exceptions, I don't understand what's going on, is anyone familiar with this?

```
pip install --no-dependencies --user -i https://artifactory.cloud.company.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-python-org/simple git+https://github.kdc.company.com/MandR/package.git
Looking in indexes: https://artifactory.cloud.company.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-python-org/simple
Collecting git+https://github.kdc.company.com/MandR/package.git
  Cloning https://github.kdc.company.com/MandR/package.git to c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ptb41on4
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 339, in check_if_exists
    self.satisfied_by = pkg_resources.get_distribution(str(no_marker))
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 476, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 352, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 895, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (tables 3.4.3 (c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('tables==3.2.0'), {'package'})
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 221, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req.check_if_exists(self.use_user_site)
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 350, in check_if_exists
    self.req.name
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 476, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 352, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 895, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (tables 3.4.3 (c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('tables==3.2.0'), {'package'})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the wrong version of the `tables` package installed. Trying installing the required version with `pip install tables==3.2.0`.